# MySQL update failed (debian)

Tags: mysql, init

I have problem updating MySQL server (pkg mysql-server5.5)
MySQL server "can't stop"

```
[FAIL] Stopping MySQL database server: mysqld failed!
invoke-rc.d: initscript mysql, action "stop" failed.
dpkg: warning: subprocess old pre-removal script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: trying script from the new package instead ...
[FAIL] Stopping MySQL database server: mysqld failed!
invoke-rc.d: initscript mysql, action "stop" failed.
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/mysql-server-5.5_5.5.44-0+deb7u1_armhf.deb (--unpack):
 subprocess new pre-removal script returned error exit status 1
[FAIL] Stopping MySQL database server: mysqld failed!
invoke-rc.d: initscript mysql, action "stop" failed.
```

Comment: Can you stop it manually?

Comment: @Braiam `sudo service mysql stop:
[FAIL] Stopping MySQL database server: mysqld failed!`

Comment: Have you tried executing a `kill` on the msyqld process (note: `kill` not `kill -9`)

Comment: I'm also having trouble upgrading that package right now; looks like a bug.

Comment: @Camil, it probably is, because I never had problem with apt-get

Comment: @Andrea SIGTERM?

Comment: Hm, in that case this is a different issue than mine.

Comment: @CamilStaps: which Debian branch are you using? Stable, testing or unstable?

Comment: @AndreadePalo stable. But I'll just wait until there's another update. I would try purging and reinstalling, but I don't have the time at the moment to backup everything. I tried simply removing though, without success.

Comment: @Camil I'm sure that purging will help, but mysql backup is painful

Comment: @David8 unfortunately, it didn't. I opened [a new question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/222129/37050) about it because it's not exactly the same as this one. I thought it was, because it was also recent.

Comment: @Camil Hm, this is weird.